# Computing JaroWinkler Similarity for unordered and different sized dataframes

Tags: pandas, data-science, information-retrieval, jaro-winkler

I have two dataframes extracted from two attached files.
I want to compute JaroWinkler Similarity for tokens inside the files. I am using below code.

```
from similarity.jarowinkler import JaroWinkler
jarowinkler = JaroWinkler()
df_gt['jarowinkler_sim'] = [jarowinkler.similarity(x.lower(), y.lower()) for x, y in zip(df_ex['abstract_ex'], df_gt['abstract_gt'])]
```

I am facing two problems:

**1. Order of the tokens are not being handled.
When position of the token 'can' and 'interesting' is changed similarity index is wrongly computed!!**

```
    Unnamed: 0   abstract_gt  jarowinkler_sim
0            0     Bipartite         1.000000
1            1   ﬂuctuations         0.914141
2            2           can         0.474747 <--|
3            3       provide         1.000000    |-- Position swapped in one file
4            4   interesting         0.474747 <--|
5            5   information         1.000000
6            6         about         1.000000
7            7  entanglement         1.000000
8            8    properties         1.000000
9            9           and         1.000000
10          10  correlations         1.000000
```

**2. Size of the dataframe might not be always same.
When one of the dataframe contains less elements my solution gives an error.**

> raise ValueError( ValueError: Length of values (10) does not match
> length of index (11)

How can I solve these two problems and compute the similarity accurately?

Thanks !!

**TSV FILES**

*1. df_ex*

```
    abstract_ex
0   Bipartite
1   fluctuations
2   interesting
3   provide
4   can
5   information
6   about
7   entanglement
8   properties
9   and
10  correlations
```

*df_gt*

```
    abstract_gt
0   Bipartite
1   ﬂuctuations
2   interesting
3   provide
4   can
5   information
6   about
7   entanglement
8   properties
9   and
10  correlations
```